# Getting data from JSON in node-red with http request

Tags: json, node-red

Disclaimer: this is my first time attempting to write in Javascript; I don't know what I am doing.

I tried looking for example of this, but everything I found has the JSON object included in Javascript. Trying to return just the price_usd from this JSON

https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/

```
[
{
    "id": "bitcoin", 
    "name": "Bitcoin", 
    "symbol": "BTC", 
    "rank": "1", 
    "price_usd": "972.935", 
    "price_btc": "1.0", 
    "24h_volume_usd": "501202000.0", 
    "market_cap_usd": "15650425175.0", 
    "available_supply": "16085787.0", 
    "total_supply": "16085787.0", 
    "percent_change_1h": "-2.35", 
    "percent_change_24h": "-17.36", 
    "percent_change_7d": "2.55", 
    "last_updated": "1483690766"
}
```

]

My current code in the linked function box is :

```
return {payload:msg.payload.price_usd};
```

msg.payload returns undefined. Tried with both http request set to return as parsed JSON object and as UTF-8 string.

Comment: you didn't name that object, you can't refer to it ... var data = {...} return data.price_usd ... show us full code this one doesn't define anything...

Comment: You need to include more information about the flow you are using. Edit the question and add a screen shot or export the flow and paste it in so we can see clearly what you are doing,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response is surrounded by `[ ]`. This indicates it's an array. So you need to reference into that array to get to the data.

```
    msg.payload[0].price_usd
```